# Ultrapowers and complemented subspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, ultrapowers

Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a Banach space $X$, and let $\mathcal{U}$ be a nontrivial ultrafilter on the set $\mathbb{N}$ of all integer numbers.

It is not difficult to see that if $Y$ is complemented in $X$ then the natural copy of the ultrapower $Y_\mathcal{U}$ in $X_\mathcal{U}$ is complemented. 
Indeed, if $P$ is a projection on $X$ onto $Y$ then $P_\mathcal{U}([x_i]):= [Px_i]$ defines a projection on $X_\mathcal{U}$ onto $Y_\mathcal{U}$.

$Q_1$: Is the converse implication true?

When $Y$ is isomorphic to a dual space then $Y$ is complemented in $Y_\mathcal{U}$. So the answer is positive.

$Q_2$: Is $(c_0)_\mathcal{U}$ complemented in $(\ell_\infty)_\mathcal{U}$?